# How to randomly post texts from a discord channel with a discord bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make a discord bot to pick a random message from a discord channel we paraphrase each other like

> "Something something." -Someone, Date.

and make it post it in any channel. Since we already format those messages like this, the bot only needs to randomly select one and post it without any alteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `channel`'s `messages` then pick a `random()` 1 and use it's data to send a quote.

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID) // you can use `message.channel` instead of this variable if you want to get the message from the channel you send the command
const randomMsg = channel.messages.cache.random(1)
message.channel.send(`"${randomMsg.content}" -${message.author}, ${message.createdAt}`)
```